# How do I know if my snails are bleeding? How can I move them place to place without hurting them?

Tags: snails

I try not to pull my snails so I wait for them to come onto my hand, but they take so much time, that is what is my difficulty. I want to also be alert to when they bleed, but I don't know where to check if it is bleeding and I don’t know their blood colours.

Comment: what type of snails do you have,please tell what type of setup you have type of food and what supliments do you give your snails.

Comment: When I crush Ramshorns for the fish to eat , it looks like a very small amount of red blood. Pond snails and asian live bearers do not seem to show any ( when crushed).

Comment: most snails have blue blood https://www.mcgill.ca/oss/article/did-you-know/snails-spiders-and-octupi-all-have-blue-blood

Comment: what makes you think your snails are bleeding? And why do yo utake them in your hands ?